# Стили в WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

По какой причине измененные стили в теме WordPress через время откатываются до изначальных. Как это исправить?

Comment: Кеши надо чистить. В браузере - ctrl+f5. Стили в файлах .css, с ними ничего произойти не может, раз уж вы их записали.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете готовую тему, скорее всего она обновляется средствами WordPress. Чтобы этого не произошло, создайте [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)